# build user chroot on first login

Tags: linux, ldap, nfs, pam, chroot

I'm using ldap for remote user authentication and I basically need to either figure out how to:

a.  chroot a user on machine b from machine a via nfs,(which doesn't seem possible without mounting more directories than I'm comfortable with)

or -------

b.  After adding a user to the ldap db on machine a, force a script to be executed on machine b during the users login that will auto chroot the user before they are allowed to do anything upon their first login.

---

I'm thinking my second option is probably the best bet, and was thinking along the lines of using pam_exec.so to call the script.  However, I have a few concerns about this approach.  First, I'm not sure if the script that will be run will have root permissions which it will need to perform the chroot.  Second, I'm not sure if pam_exec happens early enough in the login process to be an effective option.  Lastly, I need to make sure that the code works in both pam.d/ssh and pam.d/su to consider it a valid solution.

Are my concerns valid or does it seem like this would be a good solution?  Or is there a better approach to this problem.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the requirements for doing this? is this about _security_? limiting the ability of the user to execute commands? any other reason?

Comment: @dawud Basically,I want the users on the remote machine to be chrooted for the slight bit of security that chrooting offers.  However, I don't want to have to login into 2 different machines every time I add a user.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, arguably, [`chroot` might not be considered a security feature](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2013/03/27/is-chroot-a-security-feature/). There are [opinions in the other direction, as well](https://serverfault.com/questions/559463/why-running-namedbind-in-chroot-is-so-important-for-security-or-maybe-it-is-n/591833#591833).

Arguably, what you need to implement is a reproducible, auditable method of limiting the ability of the user to perform actions other than the strictly allowed.

If you register your users in LDAP, surely you have already deployed the mechanisms to perform LDAP authentication on any machine connected to this LDAP, be it by means of `sssd` or using any other PAM module, it is not relevant to the rest of the solution, and is assumed to be already in place (in my case, I'm using freeIPA and `sssd`).

To implement this scenario, what I currently do is the following (be aware that this kind of restrictions requires that several conditions are met, otherwise the restriction can be easily circumvented):

- The users do not belong to the `wheel` group, the only one authorized to use `su` (enforced via PAM). Usually, a non-LDAP user (`sysadm`) exists to allow trusted administrators performing actions in cases of disaster recovery or LDAP unavailability.
- The users are given a properly secured `rbash` with a read-only PATH pointing to a private `~/bin`, this `~/bin/` directory contains links to all allowed commands, for example:

  ```
  $ ll ~/bin
  total 0
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 14 Sep 17 08:58 clear -> /usr/bin/clear*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud  7 Sep 17 08:58 df -> /bin/df*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 10 Sep 17 08:58 egrep -> /bin/egrep*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud  8 Sep 17 08:58 env -> /bin/env*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 10 Sep 17 08:58 fgrep -> /bin/fgrep*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud  9 Sep 17 08:58 grep -> /bin/grep*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 10 Sep 17 08:58 rview -> /bin/rview*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 13 Sep 17 08:58 rvim -> /usr/bin/rvim*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 13 Sep 17 08:58 sudo -> /usr/bin/sudo*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 17 Sep 17 08:58 sudoedit -> /usr/bin/sudoedit*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 13 Sep 17 08:58 tail -> /usr/bin/tail*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 11 Sep 17 08:58 wc -> /usr/bin/wc*
  ```
- the users are given a restricted, read-only environment (think of stuff like `LESSSECURE`, `TMOUT`, `HISTFILE` variables). This is to avoid `shell` escapes from commands like `less` or `vim`.
- if MAC restrictions are in place (the specific GNU/Linux distribution you are using has SELinux enabled), the users are mapped to the SELinux user `staff_u` and given rights to execute commands as other user as required via `sudo`. The specific `sudorules` allowed need to be carefully reviewed to prevent the user from circumventing these limitations, and can also be deployed in your existing LDAP infrastructure (this is one of freeIPA features).
- the users' `/home`, `/tmp` and possibly `/var/tmp` are polyinstantiated via `/etc/security/namespace.conf`:

  ```
  /tmp       /tmp/.inst/tmp.inst-$USER-     tmpdir:create   root
  /var/tmp   /tmp/.inst/var-tmp.inst-$USER- tmpdir:create   root
  $HOME      $HOME/$USER.inst/              tmpdir:create   root
  ```

  Polyinstantiation of directories is not a new feature, it has been available for quite a long time now. As a reference, see [this article from 2006](http://www.coker.com.au/selinux/talks/sage-2006/PolyInstantiatedDirectories.html). As a matter of fact, a lot of modules already use `pam_namespace` by default, but the default configuration at `/etc/security/namespace.conf` does not enable polyinstantiation.
  Also, `/etc/security/namespace.init` should make all skeletal files read-only for the users and owned by `root`.

This way you can choose whether the users can execute any command on their own behalf (via a link in the private `~/bin` directory, provisioned via `/etc/skel`, as explained above), on behalf of other user (via `sudo`) or none at all.

Comment: this is very informative and definitely worth of a +1, but it  doesn't really answer my quetion.  Unfortunately, I'm not in charge of the security policy so I'm stuck using the chroot for now.  I think that we are using chroots to hide / limit users seeing/effecting other users actually, which would be handled by proper permissions like th article you posted says....sigh.

Comment: That is precisely what a polyinstantiated `/home` plus a properly secured `rbash` accomplishes. A user cannot see another user's home directory.

Comment: even with that being said, I still need to figure out how to trigger a script to be run by pam_exec or some other solution, as I have a script that will not only chroot users but automatically build control groups for them.  So even if I threw out the chrooting, still need the cgroups to automatically be built.

Comment: Sure, you can use `/etc/security/namespace.init` to provision `cgroups`.

Comment: ok, ok.  you've sold me.  I did ask if there was a better approach after all.  Had to look up what polyinstantiated directories are for and am looking at the relevant /etc files.  Now I just have to make the case to my boss :)  .  In case someone is frustrated by me accepting this approach, realized I could just use a subshell from the ldap server to trigger a script the remote server when adding the ldap user if I wanted to...

Comment: I've been using this kind of deployment in sensitive environments where users' access is quite limited, and so far it's been successful. Before you jump into it, though, take the time to spawn a virtual machine and test all these for your use case.

Comment: actually, I'm using Fedora, and I don't think it will support polyinstantiation of directories until version 21 :(

Comment: See my last edit.

Comment: the concept that Chroot is not a security feature is actually very outdated. If you actually read that article, it implies that the way you could break out of a chroot requires either a vulnerable daemon server process, or idomatic human error. the simple fact is that chroot provides file system visualization. this is the very same thing that systems like openvz uses. infact openvz is just a Chroot, but that which covers all the implied security provisions needed to also seperate the process table. to simply separate users, chroot is MORE than sufficient.

Comment: if your chroot is used to seperate users. if you do NOT run a daemon in the chroot. if you do not mount the /proc and /sys file systems, and if you severely limit and audit all available binaries available to the user, then an attacker would have to compromise the kernel. the same could be so for any real virtualisation technology, like proxmox and openvz. this is why sshd server, apache2, dovecot, sendmail, openVPN, and just about every server software has Chroot built in AS A SECURITY FEATURE

Comment: The article I've linked above is from a year ago. Granted, that can be a _long ago_ in technological time.

Comment: @RapidWebs it would be interesting if you share your thoughts on this question in an answer.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/559463/why-running-namedbind-in-chroot-is-so-important-for-security-or-maybe-it-is-n/591833#591833